# Minimize a window using Alt-Tab on Windows

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, window, alt-tab

Is it possible to minimize a window using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> on Windows? On a Mac, when using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and a window is selected, I can hit the <kbd>H</kbd> key to hide a window, so I was wondering if I could do the same on Windows somehow (I'm on a Mac right now so I can't test every key combination if I wanted to, anyway).

On a side note, are there any other keyboard shortcuts that are available while using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> that can help hide windows?

Comment: Windows Key + Down Arrow does what you want.

Comment: Excellent thanks, I was looking online as well for a solution but couldn't find one. I'll try this out when I can.

Comment: As far as I know, Alt+Tab does not allow minimizing windows. On the other hand, if you press Ctrl+Alt+Tab, it will show the regular Alt+Tab switcher which stays on screen when you release the keys. Then you can use arrow keys to select a window, and press Enter to switch to it. Yet other key presses return you to the previously active window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Windows 7**

- Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (*Display the System menu for the active window*) and then choose minimize with
  <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> arrows or if you have enabled the
  underline letter option you can just hit the underline letter and the
  window will minimize.
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will hide all the windows so you can see the Desktop, hit it again and the windows show up again.
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> will minimize all the Windows and
  <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> will maximize them
  again.
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> will minimize (hit twice) the window, to bring it back hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and choose the windows you minimized.
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pos1</kbd> look bellow in the comments

Comment: Win + Home will minimize all windows but the active one.

Comment: nice, now i have learned something new!

Comment: Underlined letters always work, even if the underline is hidden. To minimize the active window, you can press `Alt+Space` and then press `n` if your system language is English (and the current keyboard layout has `n`). If you click the window icon or right-click window title to display the menu, the underline is hidden but pressing `n` still minimizes the window.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between windows by simpliy pressing Alt+Tab. (If its only one window open this might not work). If you are trying to go to the desktop you can just press windows button +D (Win + D)